# Filter out all markers in google maps except for convinience stores (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I'm coding an app in flutter. I have a google api key, and have successfully set up a piece of code that makes google maps appear in the emulator zoomed into a specific selected location. Now I'm trying to make it in a way, that only nearby convinience stores are displayed in maps. Anyone knows how to filter markers so only normal convinience stores are displayed on map in flutter?

In google maps platform I tried deselecting all filters except for Shopping, but it didn't lead to a wanted result. It shows all possible stores including clothing shops etc. I only want normal larger chain supermarkets to be shown.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or a sample of a request that you sent to the API for us to understand what's wrong with  the request that filtering does not work.